# Documentação clara sobre o S@T SP

Tags: erp

Preciso integrar o SAT em meu PDV, porém eu não consigo encontrar uma documentação clara sobre esta comunicação. Pelo que pude entender eu terei que:

1. Gerar um XML do cupom
2. Assinar digitalmente
3. Enviar para o S@T via DLL (que é padrão)

Aqui ficam algumas dúvidas:

1. Onde encontro o modelo do XML, ideal seria uma documentação comentada, mas o XML Schema já ajuda.
2. Onde encontro a documentação da DLL com as chamadas possíveis?
3. Vou usar o S@T como contingência da NFCe, onde encontro quais regras se aplicam neste caso?

Não pretendo usar componentes de terceiros, então preciso da documentação oficial da receita, se é que ela existe.

Desde já agradeço, abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação existe e é bem abrangente (surpreendentemente bem feita) e está no site da [Secretaria da Fazenda de São Paulo](http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat/). A documentação está em `Legislação`, item `Legislação em vigor`.

Se você for ler toda a CAT-147 é meio tedioso. Prefira baixar os PDFs do **Manual de Orientação** e da **ER SAT** (Especificação de Requisitos). Você os encontrará em `Downloads`, item `Arquivos vigentes`. Dê uma explorada geral na página e você vai começar a formar uma ideia da coisa.

Entenda que, em um único manual, existem dois lados da documentação técnica. Uma voltada para os fabricantes de equipamentos SAT e outra voltada para os desenvolvedores de sistemas (que eles chamam de AC, aplicativo comercial). Na **ER SAT**, existe uma tabela (item 4.2.2) que relaciona todos os grupos, elementos e atributos que compõem o XML do CF-e e isso o ajudará a construir esse XML. A primeira coluna dessa tabela é importante, pois ela indica a **origem**, quem é o responsável por fornecer aquele dado. As linhas indicadas com `AC` são os dados gerados pelo seu aplicativo. Os demais serão preenchidos depois, pelo equipamento SAT.

O fluxo é simples:

1. Seu aplicativo gera um XML simples, contendo apenas os dados de responsabilidade da AC, descrevendo a venda;
2. Esse XML é enviado para o equipamento SAT através da função `EnviarDadosVenda`;
3. O equipamento SAT completa o XML, valida, assina e o devolve para seu aplicativo;
4. Seu aplicativo emite o extrato com base nos dados do XML, que é chamado de CF-e-SAT (cuja assinatura o torna um documento fiscal com validade jurídica).

Você disse que não quer usar bibliotecas de terceiros, mas nada o impede de conferir outras implementações para ajudar a compreender a coisa toda.
Eu colocaria mais links, mas eu não tenho "reputação" para isso :)

Comment: Perfeita resposta Daniel. Muito obrigado.